# Calculate Distances Between Addresses Without Google Maps

Tags: maps, distance, street-address

I bascially want to create a search in our Sales Orders database to find items that where shipped within a range of a particular address.

I can't use Google's API because:
It will be a report and there is no way to display a Map at runtime, which violates the terms of service. 
Google limits you to 1,600 requests a day, so comparing and arbitrary address to all our sales orders would violate that before 1 search completed.
I imagine running the directions API to compare the address to each order in our database would take forever.

Comment: How close are you looking?  If ZipCode works, you can do that very quick and easy at the DB level.  That will take more time

Comment: So do you need either or both of the following: 1. a geocoding API (text-location/postal code to coordinates) and/or 2. a travel-distance along roads algorithm between two points? You won't need (2) if you only care about straight line distance.

Comment: Precise distance or even driving distance is not necessary. Basically its to determine if our products are installed near a potential customer so they can look at them, so I would be looking for a 100 mile straight line distance or something.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A lot of this will depend on the precision and exactly what you want to do.

For example, if you want Line of Sight calculations, you can use a service like this one [http://geocoder.us](http://geocoder.us/)/ to get the Latitude and Longitude of each address, from this you can do a simple calculation to get the "as the crow flies" distance between this point and another.

if you want true driving direction distance, that will be much more complicated.

Comment: Good point, I assumed the original author meant straight line or great circle distances.

Comment: I think this will work, I can cache the locations by zip code so I don't have to go out to the service everytime.

Comment: In that case, you can get the lat/log for zips from Melissa Data to keep locally.  (Feel free to e-mail me if you want the SQL to do the distance calculations)

Comment: I did find a zip code file here http://www.populardata.com/zipcode_database.html, I don't know how old it is, but I don't think the list changes that much.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [Yahoo! geocoding API](http://developer.yahoo.com/geo/placefinder/) and cache the lat/lons to the database, and then use the lat/lons and standard mapping library calls to determine the distance to your point of interest.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at other geocoding APIs, like [Yahoo](http://developer.yahoo.com/geo/placefinder/) or [Bing](http://www.microsoft.com/maps/developers/web.aspx)?

There's also [this one](http://geocoder.us/help/), which says it's free and offers a few .NET code samples.